# Which repository do I add to automatically update Apache?

Tags: 11.10, updates, apache2, repository

I guess the tittle says it all: I installed apache on my ubuntu(11.10), which repository do I add to automatically update it?

Comment: **How** did you install it? The 2 opposites: 1. If it is from USC/tasksel it will automatically update. 2. If it is from source you will have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will automatically update to the latest available version for your distribution if you installed it from the Ubuntu repositories via any of the available methods: Software Center, Synaptic, or `apt-get`/`aptitude` from the terminal.

Sometimes the very latest versions of software are only available for the latest Ubuntu version, which yours is not. You may want add the Ubuntu repositories `oneiric-backports` and `oneiric-proposed` in that case; they will *sometimes* have newer versions than those in the "main" repositories.

Here's how you'd add those two from the Software Center:

- Press `Alt+F2`, type `gksudo software-center`, enter, type your password, and enter.
- Go to the Edit menu, ... Software Sources, and the Updates tab. As in the screenshot below, make sure the bottom two (Pre-released/Unsupported updates) are checked.
- Close and exit.

[image]

Comment: I installed it with a command, but I did add some old outdated repository which I now deleted as it caused problem with updating. What's the full command to add those two repositories? (I'm a bit new to linux, so not sure how to construct the right command to add a repository in the terminal/or add some line in sources)

Comment: @Happy: please see updated answer :).

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant with "Alt+F2, type gksudo software-center", terminal is Ctrl+Alt+T and I just started Software Sources app and clicked the update tab =) Thanks to your help it's solved now!